# pyqt5 QLineEdit (connect to script)

Tags: selenium, user-interface, pyqt, selenium-chromedriver, pyqt5

Hello I am currently working on a GUI with PyQt5 and attempting to connect it with my selenium web-driver script I have been able to connect the button to run the script but the only problem is that the script goes into a shopping website and checks out Items for you in particular sizes and I have put in variables inside the script and text boxes inside the GUI I want to be able to type In the size into the QLineEdit and have the script choose it here is an example of my script.

```
self.Start_Button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Window_2)
self.Start_Button_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 370, 221, 51))
self.Start_Button_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
self.Start_Button_2.setObjectName("Start_Button_2")
self.Start_Button_2.clicked.connect(self.BOT)
```

and then I define the bot below:

```
def BOT(self):
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
        from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
        import time


        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users
        URL = .....
        driver.get(URL)

        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('s'))
        #select.select_by_visible_text(Size)
```

I have text boxes for size that the user puts in and

```
    self.Item_Code_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Window_2)
    self.Item_Code_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 125, 21))
    self.Item_Code_2.setObjectName("Item_Code_2")
    self.Name_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Window_2)
```

I tried stuff like size = self.Item_Code_2.text and all that and non of it works if anyone could provide me with some help on how to connect a text box into a function script I would really apreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a QLineEdit you use the your variable then the self.(the name of it) then .text()
So in your case it would be 
Item_code = (self.Item_Code_2.text())
For combo boxes you would use .currentText()
So if you had a combo box for Sizes and stiff it would be 
Size = (self.Size_2.currentText())

```
Item_code = (self.Item_Code_2.text())
Size = (self.Size_2.currentText())
```